# Is there a tool to remesh an object such that it contains a specified number of vertices?

Tags: geometry

I am currently making a classifier for 3-D objects that uses vertex data as input, and I am using Blender to create a dataset of 3D objects. For the classifier, I need all the objects to have equal amounts of vertices. Hence I want to know if Blender has a tool for remeshing any object such that it has a specific number of vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Soooorrrttt oooff.  It will require some math on your part.  And it only works one direction (down, removing verts).

You can tweak the Decimate modifier to collapse to a ratio of vertices kept.  If you know the number of vertices you want and the number you have is look-up-able, then you can directly calculate the ratio:

for target vertex count $t$, vertex count $v$, and ratio $r$ , it is simply
$t/v=r$ .

Remember, Blender can remove vertexes all day, but it can't add any.